# How to exit a function?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Here is what I am doing. I am a reaction time game where you have to press the button after the song ended.

```
def play(melody, tempo, pause, pace=0.800):
    start = time.time()
    for i in range(0, len(melody)):  # Play song

        noteDuration = pace / tempo[i]
        buzz(melody[i], noteDuration)  # Change the frequency along the song 
note

        pauseBetweenNotes = noteDuration * pause
        time.sleep(pauseBetweenNotes)
        if time.time() >= start + rng:
            print("Click!!!")
            return
```

So my problem is that this part which I use to stop the song when the time has reach makes it exit the function so slow:

```
        if time.time() >= start + rng:
            print("Click!!!")
            return
```

My question is: How can I optimize it or make it faster by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figure it out!.
Turns out the music codes I ripped out has time.sleep(1) in it. So, my false. lol